# How to make polygon border and fill color transparency sum up to 1

Tags: r, visualization

I'm trying to visualize the result of a clustering andwould like to use polygons with wide border.

Here's what I have so far:

[image]

#### Example code:

```
x = c(2, 6, 7, 1, 8, 2, 5, 7)
y = c(3, 5, 1, 1, 1, 2, 3, 4)
l = c('A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'B2', 'E', 'F', 'G')

n = 8
pallete = topo.colors(n, alpha=0.5)

plot(NULL, NULL, bty="n", 
     ylim=c(1-0.3, 5+0.3), 
     xlim=c(1-0.3, 8+0.3), xaxt="n",
     xlab="x", ylab="y")

# grids
abline(h=1:10, v=1:10, col="gray", lty=3)

polygon(c(1,2,3), c(1,2,1), col=pallete, border=pallete, lwd=30)

axis(side=1, at=1:8) 
points(x, y, col="red", pch=19)
text(x + 0.3, y, labels=l, cex=0.7)
```

What I would like is to have the fill and border colors of the polygon sum up to transparency=1, but with alpha=0.5 for each when plotted alone (in this image I just used alpha=1 for demonstration)

[image]

Comment: Have a look at `polyoffset`, on the `polyclip` package.